# Wave Operators: Preliminary

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a free Hamiltonian $H_0$ and a perturbed one $H$.

Introduce the wave operators:
$$\Omega^\pm(H,H_0):=\mathrm{s-lim}_{\tau\to\pm\infty}e^{i\tau H}e^{-i\tau H_0}P_\text{ac}(H_0)$$
*(The existence being implicitely assumed!)*

Why do we restrict to the absolutely continuous subspace?
*(Would it work for the singular continuous subspace, too, or is it because of Riemann-Lebesgue?)*

Comment: Oh yes, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following bits comes out of Reed and Simon Vol III, and I think this helps explain the problem. You should own Vol II and Vol III if you're seriously interested in this topic.

> **Definition:** Suppose that $\Omega^{\pm}(A,B)$ exist. We say that they are **complete** if and only if
>   $$
>          \mbox{Ran}\Omega^{+}=\mbox{Ran}\Omega^{-}=\mbox{Ran}P_{ac}(A).
> $$

This definition is followed immediately by

> **Proposition:** Suppose that $\Omega^{\pm}(A,B)$ exist. Then they are complete if and only if $\Omega^{\pm}(B,A)$ exist.

Comment: Yep, but what would happen if one does the same studies with the continuous subspace instead excluding the point subspace? *(Don't own these but luckily my library provides them.)*

Comment: It becomes messy. But also keep in mind that practical problems have no singular spectrum. Until a few decades ago, singular continuous was ignored entirely because nobody could imagine how such a thing could come up for Schrodinger operators. However, Barry Simon gave an example of a potential for which you would get singular continuous spectrum. But practically speaking this is not going to happen. So if you want to study this from a Physics point-of-view--and I assume you do--then it's mostly a waste of time.

Comment: Ok so but there's not hidden secret behind that Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?

Comment: It is this Riemann-Lebesgue problem that causes incompleteness. The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, as you know, does not hold for all singular continuous measures. You might want to take a look at Barry Simon's construction to better understand the conditions required to come up with singular spectrum for a potential. He reasoned through why it would happen to construct his example. Also, take a look at Simon's list of unsolved problems, especially #7. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimonsProblems.html . Singular continuous is--practically speaking--not relevant to Physics.

Comment: Do you think it is ok to soft-delete this thread? *(Question and Answer?)* I want to tidy up and this thread seems not so important, or what do you think?

Comment: @Freeze_S : Why have you becoming recently fascinated with editing old questions? Ask another one.

Comment: Alright then I'll refurbish a superflous one. I was always like this: I do so since years  already in my notes as well as posts. I **LOVE(!!)** tyding up. :) Probably I should become a household.. ^^

Comment: @Freeze_S : If you ask a question, and you learn something at the time, acknowledge where you were and where you are now, and recognize that (a) others may well benefit from the same questions and answers and (b) others have spent time answering your questions, and you never know how much time they have spent. The question or the answer may not seem like much to you now, but when people spend the time to help, that should be respected. Honestly, I'm becoming less inclined to spend much time answering your questions because of things like this.

Comment: @Freeze_S : Just as one example, I spent quite a bit of time trying to find a good reference from Simon because I felt that was important and central to the issue. I left that in a comment. Don't you see value in things like that?

Comment: Yes I know that's why I'm carefully and politely asking. Very happy about all of your hints - they really help me alot. Thanks so much for all!!!! :) Besides I honestly have big respect of your knowledge. It's always a pleasure to read your other answers. *(You know really alot!)*

Comment: Yes I know I read your links. I remember for example the one you posted about Eberlein-Smulyan on weak convergence for Banach integration. Did it take you alot of time to find the Simon link? ...I just don't want to mess up with you. For that I have to much respect of you.